# How can I handle TypedArrays generically when some of their signatures are incompatible?

Tags: typescript

Take the simple function bellow. This is trivial in JavaScript, but in TypeScript this produces an error because `TypedArray.set` is expecting the first parameter to be of type `ArrayLike<number> & ArrayLike<bigint>`.

```typescript
type TypedArray = Int8Array | Uint8Array | Uint8ClampedArray 
| Int16Array | Uint16Array
| Int32Array | Uint32Array 
| BigInt64Array | BigUInt64Array
| Float32Array | Float64Array

function expand<T extends TypedArray>(arr: T, elementCount: number): T {
    const constructor = arr.constructor as new (length: number) => T
    const result = new constructor(arr.length + elementCount)
    result.set(arr) //error
    return result
}
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wgaOMm) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Is this what other TypeScript developers would do? If this is necessary, then it begs the question why a TypedArray type doesn't already exist.

Comment: It doesn't exist because it hasn't been implemented; there's a longstanding open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#15402](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15402) with... a few dozen upvotes.  Not the most sought-after feature in the large list of open feature requests.  Does that fully address the question now, and I should write up an answer (with a link to ms/TS#15402)? Or am I still missing something?

Comment: @jcalz You seem to have understood my question correctly, so if you believe your answer is proper, then you should write it up if you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way for something like this to work is with [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).  There is a longstanding open feature at [microsoft/TypeScript#15402](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15402) to support some sort of supertype interface for typed arrays, with a [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15402#issuecomment-743695515) that suggests defining a generic interface like:

```
interface TypedArr<T extends number | bigint> {
  readonly BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: number;
  readonly buffer: ArrayBufferLike;
  readonly byteLength: number;
  readonly byteOffset: number;
  /* ✂ ⋯ omitted for brevity ⋯ ✂ */
  join(separator?: string): string;
  keys(): IterableIterator<number>;
  lastIndexOf(searchElement: T, fromIndex?: number): number;
  readonly length: number;
  /* ✂ ⋯ omitted for brevity ⋯ ✂ */
  reverse(): this;
  set(array: ArrayLike<T>, offset?: number): void;
  slice(start?: number, end?: number): TypedArr<T>;
  /* ✂ ⋯ omitted for brevity ⋯ ✂ */
  valueOf(): TypedArr<T>;
  values(): IterableIterator<T>;
  [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<T>;
  [index: number]: T;
}
```

and then you can use `TypedArr<number>` or `TypedArr<bigint>` to represent most of the functionality you needed in your [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types):

```
function expand<T extends number | bigint>(arr: TypedArr<T>, elementCount: number): TypedArr<T> {
  const constructor = arr.constructor as new (length: number) => TypedArr<T>
  const result = new constructor(arr.length + elementCount);
  result.set(arr);
  return result;
}

declare const a64: BigInt64Array;
expand(a64, 3); // okay
declare const a32: Int32Array;
expand(a32, 4); // okay
```

This may or may not ever make it into the standard library, but even if it doesn't you can just define it yourself for your code base.  That's not an optimal experience, but as workarounds go it's pretty good since it behaves the same either way.

---

Or, depending on your needs, you could make a type that captures only those pieces of `TypedArray` that you will use inside your function.  Maybe like:

```
interface TypedArrLike extends ArrayLike<number | bigint> {
  set(array: ArrayLike<number | bigint>, offset?: number): void;
}

function expand<T extends TypedArrLike>(arr: T, elementCount: number): T {
  const constructor = arr.constructor as new (length: number) => T
  const result = new constructor(arr.length + elementCount)
  result.set(arr)
  return result
}

declare const a64: BigUint64Array;
expand(a64, 3); // okay
declare const a32: Int32Array;
expand(a32, 4); // okay
```

which produces a similar result without needing a huge interface.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkqJLAsgGICuGGehRSAlsAC4QBOAZuUgCoBPGBAAmAQQ4cAPHyQQAHu2AioxKmABGnJAB8kGpgHMWrAHz1GjDhBAiA9sAwCkAIQCafAKIBlAPoAFTwAlX08AGU8AWU8AOT4ALjVNTgBuBktrWwcnfSouLk5EiQ4QARc8go4wpgBrCDTLIkz7R2cNAXYwiGBDVgALROB1LQ4Gxubsto6IAHl8qAhWQeHU9MZ4OxgBAHUmfpYAClYQDkNF5eSOABokKGOOVgB+C5Gb7pFnpJGASkT9qDGlm6rA4TGgB1+SAAkuwShoMBAYZwQKw7NIANpDS43PgAXVMgMYEAAbpwBAcYNYREx0OxEgdiZgqBBEnwbiwRAoXpwbicSgJWUJRMUZKZvkgALzmDR2OwIkDAG7-CSGT4KgSQmVymzAQlELhMWgMpks-g3O4nJ7c65yZSfLE-P59JgAtb6w2wilUmko03GjDM1ns5Rcr48pB80qC4TiSSi8VSiPAARK51QFVq5OQwQxkV8AlupAG5Re0Q+ulIf2Bs3MEPya28yRR-hC2PSfMJ6Wy+WKpDK06ZjWs3RIKgh4uiPVFjlQuul6m0v2MgOmtm1zn1sM2yMClu5uMdyVd7UK1MujOJdWQh2rRpFtGeBB9A7oWgaBA1LjAenL6trjmhje25NruObCgeYpHkgxJ2EwIhnumA6XlmiQwXBU4sPAAaclABwLCc8B9J4CKQGwQZFhwdhgLOG72isHCat2OoYXWcx4TYHCEcRECkUsNZcJR1F1nRlzXvRU4AFawcA7FwCUqIcJ8dygj0kLKSwhhTnUAi4ZCSJwgi+komiUhAQWd4YCAdw0QobH4ZxREkcC5ECVRNnyCJjpblOEytEgCI9P01pTmAIAwC+mAYO+8Cft+la-quwYbg2EYgdG4HtpBiZrv2qrIUOe4ZaKPmiFQiARW+H5fvSlIkkwdhUFAABqJrkfAVCSMCLUrm1HXWGw7kpTu6VtvGUF8NmJUiGVEBSAAqqYFVRVVcWlsS9WNd11ZzTc7WdWwW2JUge39awg1bo2-IjXmWXmDttZ7EwmCHYkc2QnNU0zUERh9KwS3RbFNXWOtDXNa1NYnV14NrpDA11kNaWFaNh7ZZNhZUl9P2sPNi2vstMXVZWtUg5t4P3bDrAvRDfXAudQGXc2YHI7dSD3Swj3PWT70laSHALBCToulOCx-cNSDFKU1R1KKNx2PMiyeZwkJoSIwsYDSEB4fcVoXbaHzWtmrY3cLVGa7VC6+j+0NJYB9EM6BRsQZ2+hMaefZpheSYFVqPYmw8L5UXJEAUMAnwHCA5EaKyztASOE2C66d5QFQ74gQcWjGKHKXvIrDHXRBU6omEdivhA3gghpAu3BXPSF3Y5cqYYVfqbXhYJWxhv7plU4JbpiRGfCiKwsZ3eFui3gCJocoAHR7MiCm4lXA+GcPCnFWPAGbkBuKsoSAC++CH5YXBjvArD1cAcjyHAygyFfSgqFuI4GJnZjh5I+eZW8TlsAAwg1ZEtydyKvmCwjQNjADuMdBwykyoKUlKlDg08IGwLPmiCMqhgAQAAO6VgCr0AYQDxqO0yoWFBrAkDWGThgChEpiA4OgZAkEcC0TvyQfg-oSAADUcgf6sH-mOVg3x0bQBoKwaeIs2HCLvNYVgHVL5ULEWsA+axORYROMgchEYABsAAWRILgjBzRMHoiWAhCQKBviIcOeibgAGZviEjUZZawjCoEgDsQAJn7mwLxZiLHXwVNYjxnibi6McQwFRRASDQDgIgJAkR2b0DWCYTgPB4lM2KFLZACgH6qDMdk0y9Fn5GBMOYAgSdFhsObAU2os1Y56BfmU2W8sdZAWVrBVWyij6MBPsAM+F8r5WLvrk94qhMmSGyYtPk5EIB8IEYA9pw4KngJgRQ8hHAWEcAQXyZBazNloO2VZehuCDgcMIe08aZC1mUNETQhBWDcEbK2Ww6e5zuG8J4sCBZQiRHUPEZIvk0jxiLHkbc-53TVEQHUa4rRIA9EGKMSY3R-i1iWKCTY3R9iImWGcRotxFCQk+NYH4kCASrHhy8WEiJkT8B7yAA)